# what's the mechanism of formation of succinimide ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am forming succinimide ester:

[image]

Below is the experimental protocol I have adapted from ([*ACS Chem. Biol.* **2012,** *7*(2), 316–321](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/cb200374e)) pg 7 in supporting information:

> #### Formation of Activated Ester
>
> **N-Succinimidyl Trifluoroacetate** (15.0 mmol, 5 equiv) was placed in a flask. The flask was
> backfilled with Nitrogen, capped with a rubber septum, and maintained under an argon atmosphere. To the flask were
> added THF (15 mL, 0.2 M) and **2,2-dimethoxyacetic acid** (3.00 mmol, 1 equiv). Pyridine (1.69 mL, 21.0 mmol, 7 equiv) was added by syringe dropwise (over 3
> min, slightly exothermic). The mixture was stirred in the dark (3 h, producing a homogeneous solution), quenched with water (5 mL, 5 min), and diluted with DCM (45 mL) and water (50 mL). The organic phase was isolated, the aqueous phase was further extracted with a mixture of DCM and THF (3:1, 25 mL), and the combined organic phases were washed with sodium bisulfate (0.1 M aqueous, 40 mL) and dried with sodium sulfate. Volatiles were removed under reduced pressure

1. Could somebody provide the mechanism of this reaction? My guess is that pyridine abstracts hydrogen in the carboxylic acid, and the lone pair on oxygen attacks the carbonyl centre in N-Succinimidyl Trifluoroacetate.. Is this correct? I could not rationalise why 5 equiv. would be needed.
2. The reaction did not quite work out and I think it may be attributed to the fact that I did not have pure N-Succinimidyl Trifluoroacetate to begin with. When forming N-Succinimidyl Trifluoroacetate, I saw two peaks in 19F NMR at $\delta \: \pu{-72.14 ppm}$ and $\delta \: \pu{-75.62 ppm}$. I believe a peak at $\delta \: \pu{-75.62 ppm}$ was unreacted Trifluoroacetic anhydride. The 1H NMR showed that there was some unreacted N-OH succinimide. I want to figure out what kinds of side products these unreacted materials have led, but to do that, I believe I must understand the mechanism of this reaction first.

Would appreciate any help or guidance

Comment: Your suggested mechanism is only the first step which would generate the mixed anhydride of TFA and dimethoxy acetic acid. What has to happen then is the O- of the N-hydroxysuccinimide has to attack the mixed anhydride. Remember the pyridine that is present can also act as a nucleophile displacing the hydroxy succinimide from the starting material. I think the mixed anhydride is the key intermediate.

Comment: @Waylander: Agreed! The pyridine cleaves the TFA (exotherm) group and the resultant salt forms the mixed anhydride. This step should be reversible back to the starting material because the TFA half of the mixed anhydride is more reactive. Ultimately, the dimethoxy acetic acid half of the mixed anhydride reacts irreversibly with N-hydroxysuccinimide.

Comment: @Waylander thank you. But by the sound of it, I still should have got some product out but I don't see anything. Do you think there is any chance that sodium bisulfate has hydrolysed the acetal group?

Comment: The pKa of sodium bisulfate is 1.99 so yes it is quite possible you hydrolysed the acetal

Comment: @Waylander Would using brine, NaHCO3 and NH4Cl solve the issue?

Comment: The reason for using bisulfate is to remove pyridine. Do you need to remove this for the next step? Hard vac down, redissolve in DCM and citric acid wash should remove most of it. A further wash with aq Cu(II)  should remove it all.

Comment: @Waylander Thanks for your insight. I may skip using citric acid as it can again destroy my acetal but will use Cu (II) solution

Comment: Pyridine boils at 115 so dilution with toluene followed by hard vac down should remove most of it.

Comment: I would also pay attention to the water content of all substrates and reagents used. THF is also notorious for picking up water.

Comment: @Waylander so using _N_-Succinimidyl Trifluoroacetate has failed and thinking of using DIC with N-OH Suc... (want to avoid using DCC as I have been told that removing DCU is extremely difficult) would DIC (diisopropylcarbodiimide) work in this case?

Comment: It would, but there are also diimides with a remote tertiary amine that are easier to remove than DIC residues

Comment: Have a look here:  http://documents.bachem.com/coupling_reagents.pdf

Comment: @Waylander Thank you. They suggested EDAC · HCl etc but I am scared that the HCl might hydrolyse my acetal groups.. maybe I should try with DIC first.

Comment: The HCl is tied up with the tertiary base so should not be able to protonate your acetal. If in doubt have a bit of extra tertiary base present.

Comment: @Waylander I have done it. After stirring for some time, I have filtered using celite, and dried of solvent (THF). I have 3 major singlets: $\delta \: \pu{4.840 ppm}$ (1H), $\delta \: \pu{3.432 ppm}$ (7.26H), and $\delta \: \pu{2.731 ppm}$ (6.36H) + many other impurity peaks. As you can see, the integration ratios are all off (while chemical shifts kinda make sense) think my crude is just too impure to draw out any conclusion. The issue is.. I don't think my product will stay stable in the silica. Do you have any suggestions? Would appreciate any advice& thoughts

Comment: What is your ultimate goal with this product? Are you reacting it with a nucleophile?

Comment: @Waylander Bioconjugation. It will be reacting with the amine group on my amino acid

Comment: How precious is the amino acid? I would be inclined to run the reaction with the crude N-hydroxysuccinimde material and try to purify the product. Alternatively you could try to make the mixed anhydride of the dimethoxy acetic acid with BOC-anhydride using the conditions described here https://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v87-106